# inequality $|e^{ix}-1| \le 2^{1-p} |x|^p \quad (x \in \mathbb{R}, \; 0<p<1)$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I am looking for hints on a proof approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$e^{ix}-1
=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)-1
=(\cos(x)-1)+i\sin(x)
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
|e^{ix}-1|^2
&=(\cos(x)-1)^2+\sin^2(x)\\
&=\cos^2(x)-2\cos(x)+1+\sin^2(x)\\
&=2(1-\cos(x))\\
&=2(2\sin^2(x/2))\\
&=4\sin^2(x/2)\\
\end{array}
$

So you want
$|2\sin(x/2)|
\le 2^{1-p}|x|^p
= 2|x/2|^p
$
or,
if $z = x/2$,
$|\sin(z)|
\le z^p
$.

I'll stop here,
noting that $z$ is real.

Comment: The trig identity is $1-\cos x = 2 \sin^2 (x/2)$, but I knew what you meant and it was exactly what I needed.

Comment: I'll fix it. Thanks. Upvoted. Annoying.